# SQL Query for desired output

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains countries:

```
Countries
============
Australia
South Africa
Bangladesh
New zeland
Sri Lanka
England
...
```

Desired out put is

```
Country
===========
India
Sri Lanka
Followed by other countries in `Asc` or `Desc`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/837cc/3/0)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Countries
ORDER BY
  CASE Name
     WHEN 'India' THEN 0
     WHEN 'Sri Lanka' THEN 1
     ELSE 10
  END ASC,
  Name ASC -- DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @lad2025.

Comment: @MaheshH Don't forget to mark as answer ;)

Comment: Sorry @lad2025, it was my first post so wasnt aware of it
Have now marked it as answer